# opscenter 6 failed query to node - take-snapshot timeout

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter, datastax-startup

I upgraded from Opscenter 5.2.0 to 6.0.7 yesterday (this is DSE 4.8.10) following the instructions [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/opscenter/upgrdFromFormerStandaloneInstall.html). After the upgrade, I noticed that all the scheduled backup jobs were missing. The Activity tab for Backup Service took forever to load and gave me some timeout errors. I added a timeout to the opscenterd.conf to resolve that issue.

```
[ui]
 default_api_timeout=400
```

then I added my simple scheduled job - Backup On Server daily, 2 column families. I saved the job, then scheduled it to "Run Now". The backup failed with the following error:

```
Failed query to http://10.0.30.161:61621/ops/take-snapshot?req-id=78c53af6-bc02-49f2-b9a2-89452ec91cc9 : The http request to the agent timed out. This most likely indicates that you need to restart the agent on this node.
```

All agents are Up according to the Opscenter UI. Did I miss something during the upgrade? Or is there a known issue with 6.0.7?

EDIT: I found these errors in the agent.log

`INFO [qtp203625144-16505] 2017-01-05 14:15:43,183 HTTP: :put /agent-conf {} - 200
  INFO [qtp203625144-16506] 2017-01-05 14:15:43,184 HTTP: :get /connection-status {} - 200
  WARN [qtp203625144-16505] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,175 Unrecognized config key:  :rollup_subscriptions
  WARN [qtp203625144-16505] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,176 Unrecognized config key:  :destinations
  WARN [qtp203625144-16505] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,176 Unrecognized config key:  :f8c8f581a1a94776a052c25149156860
  WARN [qtp203625144-16505] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,176 Unrecognized config key:  :6ed69a25565942e9b7d65f17f754f7db
  WARN [qtp203625144-16505] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,176 Unrecognized config key:  :7109d86e3c68442a98cfc6ecc6da5b26
  WARN [qtp203625144-16505] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,176 Unrecognized config key:  :64707f80a8d242c392ba5331e1d5f545
  WARN [qtp203625144-16505] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,177 Unrecognized config key:  :02238b5e495c4e47af5214ce70640b45
  INFO [qtp203625144-16505] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,177 Got new config [note values in address.yaml override those from OpsCenter]: {:rollup_subscriptions [], :destinations ["02238b5e495c4e47af5214ce70640b45" "6ed69a25565942e9b7d65f17f754f7db" "64707f80a8d242c392ba5331e1d5f545" "7109d86e3c68442a98cfc6ecc6da5b26" "f8c8f581a1a94776a052c25149156860"], :metrics_ignored_column_families "", :f8c8f581a1a94776a052c25149156860 {:delete_this "False", :throttle_bytes_per_second "0", :path "cassandra-prod-bkup", :provider "s3", :access_key "*REDACTED*", :access_secret "*REDACTED*"}, :metrics_enabled true, :6ed69a25565942e9b7d65f17f754f7db {:throttle_bytes_per_second "0", :delete_this "False", :path "cass-prod-opsc6", :server_side_encryption "False", :provider "s3", :access_key "*REDACTED*", :access_secret "*REDACTED*"}, :cassandra_log_location "/var/log/cassandra", :hosts ["10.0.30.161"], :jmx_user "*REDACTED*", :kerberos_service "", :7109d86e3c68442a98cfc6ecc6da5b26 {:delete_this "False", :throttle_bytes_per_second "0", :path "cassandra-prod-bkup", :provider "s3", :access_key "*REDACTED*", :access_secret "*REDACTED*"}, :config_md5 "840a5bf32f266bf8c74be84adaad0520", :monitored_cassandra_pass "*REDACTED*", :monitored_thrift_port 9160, :metrics_ignored_solr_cores "", :rollups60_ttl 604800, :max_pending_repairs 5, :api_port "61621", :cassandra_port 9042, :jmx_pass "*REDACTED*", :64707f80a8d242c392ba5331e1d5f545 {:delete_this "False", :throttle_bytes_per_second "0", :path "cassandra-prod-bkup", :provider "s3", :access_key "*REDACTED*", :access_secret "*REDACTED*"}, :kerberos_keytab_location "", :rollups300_ttl 2419200, :cassandra_pass "*REDACTED*", :metrics_ignored_keyspaces "system, system_traces, system_auth, system_distributed, dse_auth, OpsCenter", :use_ssl false, :cassandra_user "*REDACTED*", :monitored_cassandra_user "*REDACTED*", :thrift_port 9160, :storage_keyspace "OpsCenter", :monitored_cassandra_port 9042, :kerberos_client_principal "", :02238b5e495c4e47af5214ce70640b45 {:delete_this "False", :throttle_bytes_per_second "0", :path "cassandra-prod-bkup", :provider "s3", :access_key "*REDACTED*", :access_secret "*REDACTED*"}, :cassandra_install_location "", :restore_req_update_period 1, :jmx_port 7199, :ec2_metadata_api_host "169.254.169.254", :rollups86400_ttl 0, :jmx_operations_pool_size 4, :backup_staging_dir "", :rollups7200_ttl 31536000}
  INFO [qtp203625144-16505] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,179 Configuration change for component class opsagent.backups.destinations.DestinationService: before: {:dest-map {"db4533f0dad548499089bbcfcc03e2fa" {:throttle_bytes_per_second "0", :delete_this "False", :path "cass-prod-opsc6", :server_side_encryption "False", :provider "s3", :access_key "*REDACTED*", :access_secret "*REDACTED*"}}, :destinations [nil nil "db4533f0dad548499089bbcfcc03e2fa" "64707f80a8d242c392ba5331e1d5f545" "7109d86e3c68442a98cfc6ecc6da5b26" "f8c8f581a1a94776a052c25149156860"]}, after: {:destinations [nil nil "64707f80a8d242c392ba5331e1d5f545" "7109d86e3c68442a98cfc6ecc6da5b26" "f8c8f581a1a94776a052c25149156860"]}
  INFO [async-dispatch-13] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,180 Starting system.
  INFO [async-dispatch-13] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,181 Configuration change for component class opsagent.backups.destinations.DestinationService: before: {:dest-map {"db4533f0dad548499089bbcfcc03e2fa" {:throttle_bytes_per_second "0", :delete_this "False", :path "cass-prod-opsc6", :server_side_encryption "False", :provider "s3", :access_key "*REDACTED*", :access_secret "*REDACTED*"}}, :destinations [nil nil "db4533f0dad548499089bbcfcc03e2fa" "64707f80a8d242c392ba5331e1d5f545" "7109d86e3c68442a98cfc6ecc6da5b26" "f8c8f581a1a94776a052c25149156860"]}, after: {:destinations [nil nil "64707f80a8d242c392ba5331e1d5f545" "7109d86e3c68442a98cfc6ecc6da5b26" "f8c8f581a1a94776a052c25149156860"]}
  INFO [async-dispatch-13] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,181 The following components have had a config change and will be rebuilt and restarted:  (:destination-service)
  INFO [async-dispatch-13] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,181 The component restart for  (:destination-service)  when accounting for dependencies requires these components to be restarted  #{:destination-service}
  INFO [async-dispatch-13] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,182 Starting DynamicEnvironmentComponent
  INFO [async-dispatch-13] 2017-01-05 14:16:16,207 Finished starting system.`

Comment: Just to confirm did you restart the agent?

Comment: Yeah, I restarted datastax-agent several times on all the nodes. the HTTP still times out, although JMX stays Up.

Comment: Can you email your SA for the startup program?  We will post the answer to SO once we have it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll send an email today.